# Check if user exists and store his data with Firebase+Angular+Facebook

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire

I have a Facebook signup method and i want it to check if the user is already persists in my Firebase. If it is, i'd like to set this data to $rootScope.loggedInUser to share across controllers.

Here's the implementation of this idea.
The problem is — no data written to firebase as well as no redirection performed.
It seems that i miss something obvious. Any ideas?

Firebase v2.0.4 
AngularFire 0.9.0
Angular 1.2.20

```
$scope.loginFacebook = function() {
    $scope.auth.$authWithOAuthPopup("facebook")
        .then(function(authData) {
            var userId = authData.uid

            function checkIfUserExists(userId) {
              (new Firebase(USERS)).child(authData.uid).once('value', function(snapshot) {
                var exists = (snapshot.val() !== null);
                userExistsCallback(userId, exists);
              });
            }    

            function userExistsCallback(exists) {
              if (exists) {
                var loggedInUser = $firebase(new Firebase(USERS).child(authData.uid)).$asObject();
                loggedInUser.$loaded().then(function() {
                  $rootScope.loggedInUser = loggedInUser;
                  $window.location.href = '#/profile';
                });
              } else {  
                $firebase(new Firebase(USERS).child(authData.uid))
                    .$update({
                        "uid": authData.uid,
                        "email": authData.facebook.email,
                        "displayName": authData.facebook.displayName,
                        "image": authData.facebook.cachedUserProfile.picture.data.url
                    })
                    .then(function(authData) {
                        $rootScope.loggedInUser = {
                            'uid': authData.uid,
                            'email': authData.facebook.email,
                            'displayName': authData.facebook.displayName,
                            'image': authData.facebook.cachedUserProfile.picture.data.url
                        }
                        var loggedInUser = $firebase(new Firebase(USERS).child(authData.uid))
                        $rootScope.loggedInUser = loggedInUser.$asObject();
                        $window.location.href = '#/profile';
                    });
              }                        
        }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you step through the code in a debugger yet? Does it reach your `userExistsCallback`? With the correct value for `exists`?

Comment: It seems that you don't call the function checkIfUserExists but just define it. Next to that there is a small semantic error in defining the variable userId (you don't close it with ;).